# How to avoid a too long line in vue.js attributes/props?

Tags: vue.js

Example:

```
<span 
  v-for='item in items'
  :style="{Veeeeeeeerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrlooooooooooooooooonnnngggggg: item.something}"
</span>
```

My linter complains about it exceeding maximum line length, how do I solve it?

*Edited*

Answer (score 2):

You can use `computed` properties or `method` for this:

```
<span 
  v-for='item in items'
  :style="getStyle(item)"
</span>

{
  methods: {
    getStyle (item) {
       return {Veeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrlooooooooooooooooonnnnngggggggg}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But what if the style needs to be different for each iteration of `item`, which is not accessible by computed value?